# c# function, validate url within mvc app

Tags: c#, validation, url

I'm trying to build a function within my mvc app that will validate the user's url input. in my code below, i get the "not all code paths return a value." I need help figuring out why it doesn't like when i return result. thanks!

```
public static long InsertUrl(string inputUrl)
        {
            long result = 0;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputUrl))
            {

                using (ShortUrlEntities db = new ShortUrlEntities())
                {

                    if (inputUrl.IndexOf(@"://test/") == -1)
                    {
                        inputUrl = "http://test/" + inputUrl;
                    }

                    Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("(([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+\\-\\.]*:)?/{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?(#[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?");
                    if (RgxUrl.IsMatch(inputUrl))
                    {
                        ShortURL su = new ShortURL();
                        su.url = inputUrl;
                        db.AddToShortURLSet(su);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        result = su.id;
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an If

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputUrl))
```

and your return is inside that if. In the event that the inputUrl is null or empty, you are not returning anything.

Move your return Result; to outside the if.

Comment: too easy, i guess i had been looking at the code too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputUrl))
```

fails then no result will ever be returned. This is needed for all function that return a value not just in MVC.